# How to access variables declared in other files in C?

Tags: c, extern, variable-declaration, linkage, one-definition-rule

Hi this is probably a stupid question but I don't know how to solve this after looking online. In a file which we will call `filea.h` under `project/a/aa/filea.h` I have a variable declared (global) `bool is_testing = false;`.

In another file called `fileb.c` under `project/b/bb/fileb.c` I have the following:

```
#include <a/aa/filea.h>
...
int ex_func(void)
{
  is_testing = true;
}
```

I am getting this error when I try to compile: `filea.h:19: first defined here`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It is reporting an error in `filea.h`, but you chose to neither show the full error message to us nor this file...

Comment: Use the `extern` keyword. You may want to take a look at [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

This declaration in the header

```
bool is_testing = false;
```

is also a definition of the variable. So the variable will defined as many times as the header will be included in different translation units.

Place in the header

```
extern bool is_testing;
```

and in some module write

```
bool is_testing = false;
```

for example where the function is defined..